# String getting overwritten in for loop

Tags: java

I am iterating through a for loop, reading contents from a file, storing the result in a string. How do I prevent the string from getting overwritten inside my for loop?

I am doing this -

```
for(File file:files) {
    String fileContent = readFileContents(file.getAbsolutePath()); // this is getting overwritten
}
```

Comment: You store it somewhere else, may be in an array or a `List`...?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redefining your `String` with every iteration of for loop. Move declaration of String outside the loop.

```
String fileContent = "";
for(File file:files) {
    fileContent += readFileContents(file.getAbsolutePath()); 
}
```

Also [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is a better choice for string manipulations.

So this is an efficient soution:

```
StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();
for(File file:files) {
    fileContent.append(readFileContents(file.getAbsolutePath())); 
}
```

Comment: No this did not work. Still see the string getting overwritten

Comment: @user3751169 There is no way that string will be overwritten with the mentioned code. Check your file contents, use print statements or debugger to understand what is happening.

Comment: Sure. Let me try. Accepting your answer for now.

Comment: That's an assumption.  The OP might not want to "merge" the contents of the files into a single variable...

Comment: @MadProgrammer My answer is based on the wording of question, which reads "I am iterating through a for loop, reading contents from a file, storing the result in a string" .

Comment: @JunedAhsan And that still means nothing to me ;) - The op might want to process the contents individually...the OPs not provided enough context to be able to provide a concrete answer...Not a downvoted scenarios in my eyes, but the question is vague and open to (mis)interruption ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Perhaps this answer falls under the category "not so vague answers to vague question" :-p

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the String Variable in Loop so, on each iteration the new instance ll be created and the old one ll be overwritten.

```
String fileContent = ""; 

for(File file:files) {
    fileContent = fileContent + " : " + readFileContents(file.getAbsolutePath()); // this is getting overwritten
}
```

or use `StringBuilder` that ll append new data to string.

OR

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

for(File file:files) {
        str.append(readFileContents(file.getAbsolutePath())); 
}
System.out.println(str);
```

If you want to store each data as single / separate then you can use :

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
for(File file:files) {
            strList.add(readFileContents(file.getAbsolutePath()));
}
```

Comment: That's an assumption.  The OP might not want to "merge" the contents of the files into a single variable...

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Now See my answer Update Sir. Is it ok ?

Comment: Yep covers more bases ;)

Comment: @user3145373 looks good! I would only leave out the argument in your StringBuilder declaration. The StringBuilder class will initialize the stringbuilder with a capacity of 16 characters or when you provide a string to the constructor it will intialize it with the length of the provided string + 16char. Since your provided String has length 0, it is redundant. ;)

Comment: @Arno_Geismar - Sorry for that, in hurry I just forgot to do that, i have updated the answer. Thanks for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I would use stringbuilder for this. String concatination is more efficient that way.
To refer to you problem, since your declaration is inside the for loop, the value of your string is overwritten each time it iterates. Moving the declaration outside the loop won't fix this problem entirely since it will still be overwritten with a new value. by using concatination you can achieve your desired result.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(File file:files) {
sb.append(readFileContents(file.getAbsolutePath()));
}
System.out.println("sb = " + sb.toString());
```

You can also save the strings in an ArrayList if you just want to have all the filepaths seperately.

```
String filepath = "";
List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
for(File file: files) {
paths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
}

for(String s : paths){
System.out.println("filepath: " + s );
}
```

Comment: Without knowing anything else, I would argue this is the closest answer we have to meeting the ... vague... requirements of the OP